# How to access Power Saving Mode Programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, save

I need to access to programmatically turn ON & OFF Power Saving Mode in android.
Is there any API for this ? As I can see Power Saving mode option is not available
for all mobile devices, is there any code to check these settings availability and if available then turn it ON and OFF ?

Also is there any work around ?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609978/power-saving-mode-in-android-controlled-programatically][1] sorry but you can't do that


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609978/power-saving-mode-in-android-controlled-programatically

Comment: Yes I gone through it. But wanted to know has Samsung provided any such APIs for Power Saver Mode enabled devices ?

Comment: You can use the  PowerManager.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html.

Answer (score 8):

*If you want to test the Power Saving Mode (PSM):*

The following works with Android Studio 3.4.1 and a Google Pixel 2 XL phone:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug # a charging device cannot enter PSM
$ adb shell settings put global low_power 1 # enter Power Saving Mode (PSM)
```

This only works on devices that has the standard Power Saving Mode, like Samsung's, but not Huawei's, for example. On some Samsung devices, this setting is stored in global setting keyed `psm_switch`, as mentioned above.

You can leave PSM by setting low_power to 0 or by enabling charging again with:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#testing_doze_and_app_standby

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to control the user's device settings from your app.

Rather consider suspending background services when battery levels are low.

Or to notify the user of low battery power and advising the user to switch of unnecessary settings like Bluetooth or WiFi.

Comment: dude maybe somebody may need to because there is an issue with finding the option

Comment: Firstly, that answer was written in 2015 when a lot of things were still restricted or not available yet, so there's that, but secondly, theoretically, you could use the PowerManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager). The point was always that messing with the user's device settings was considered an invasion of privacy...

Comment: It may be a questioner's phone, / a case of user=the programmer, and it's not considered an invasion of privacy if you are the user/programmer and it's your phone.  So just saying "bad practice" and not saying how, is avoiding the question.

Comment: That's fair. I could have written a comment on his question rather than an answer like this. However, if the asker wanted it for use in their app (which they're not clear about in the question), then my answer would have been legit.

Answer (score 0):

Most devices won't have a built-in power-saver API, so you could try to make your own power-saver mode by turning off the bluetooth if it's on, the wi-fi, etc, deactivating location in settings, or checking for other power-eating options enabled.

Comment: But when I run my own Power Saver application on devices which are having in-build Power Saver Mode, then what will be the behavior of settings ? Also the in-build Power Saver does some extra battery saving work like decreasing display refresh rate, turning off half of the CPU core.. that wont be done by coding right ?

Comment: You are talking about a Samsung, most likely. Well, in that case I recommend this http://developer.samsung.com/develop

Comment: Yes I checked SDK too but havn't find any reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are no available API's to do this in android SDK. however You can control/save the power  by Turning off Blutooth,Wi-Fi and other unused sevices inside your coding.

Comment: Can you just check my response to @WishMaster.

Comment: In my experience Samsung, as well as HTC, is one of the manufacturers that modify Android OS in most unpredictable ways. 

 "power saving mode" is not an official AOSP feature and there are no ways to detect it via official SDK. There are some possible ways how you can work around it though.

Comment: Ok. Thanks All. I think I need to go for option two.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the power saving mode programmatically. Allowing this would be a bad idea.

On certain Samsung devices you can check if it is enabled:

```
final String result = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "psm_switch");
Log.v("Debug", "Powersaving active: " + TextUtils.equals(result, "1"));
```

See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296959/3600178