# how to enable power saver mode in android samsung mobile

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, battery-saver

Kindly give some example or idea for enabling the power saver mode from android code for samsung devices as well as moto devices programmatically.Or else kindly give some example for navigating the user to the battery saver settings page from app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically enable/disable "Battery Saver" mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234502/programmatically-enable-disable-battery-saver-mode)

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25103642/7073808) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195469/how-to-access-power-saving-mode-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: thanks @NileshRathod

Comment: most welcome @aashishcool happy to help you