# what permission in manifest to put application in power saving android

Tags: android, performance, power-saving

what permission in manifest to put application in power saving android.
when user turn on power saving mode and try to add my application in list of applications that can run in this mode.
it tried this permission and no change

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73489921/12272687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this links its useful for you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609978/power-saving-mode-in-android-controlled-programatically

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133392/find-out-if-power-saving-mode-enabled-android-sdk