# Background service stops in battery saver mode in android R

Tags: android, battery, background-service, battery-saver

I wrote an android app that checks battery level by changing level and gives an alarm when the level reaches a certain value.
I made use of broadcast receiver and background service in my app.
It works properly in all android versions but in android R service stops when battery saver mode is turned on.
I tested my app on several emulator and real device with different android versions and works properly but has problem in android R.
Is there a way to prevent the service from stopping?

my Service class :

```
public class BatService extends Service {

  private BatReceiver receiver = new BatReceiver();

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    BatteryLevelAsync async = new BatteryLevelAsync();
    async.execute();

    return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private class BatteryLevelAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has imposed restrictions on Android 8 to optimize the battery.
This restricts background work even when using services.
I found an solution to solve this problem: use PowerManager.

Add permission to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

And add below code to your Activity :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  String packageName = context.getPackageName();
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    context.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Kotlin** use like this:

```
 @SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
    fun permissionBattery() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val packageName: String = baseContext.packageName
            val pm: PowerManager =
                baseContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                baseContext.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

then the user can change the default settings for **Battery Sever**