# Execute a last methode on the onDestroy methode [Java] [Android]

Tags: java, android, paho

I'm having a MainActivity, which start a foreground service as an intent with the methode ContextCompat.startForegroundService this service has an instance of paho MQTT connection.

When I closed the application, I want to send a last message in MQTT to warn that the application going to be closed, but this didn't work all the time, namely when I'm not connecting to my computer with the android studio debugger.

So have you any idea to help me ?

More informations :

On the onDestroy() methode of MainActivity :

```
getApplicationContext().stopService(intent);
```

On the onDestoy() of my service :

```
    client.published(client.GetTopic(),client.TAG_CLOSE);

    try {
        client.client.disconnect();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("destroy service", "ERROR !!!!");
    }
```

EDIT : I discovered that the problem, appear when I turn on the battery saving.

Comment: "*I want to send a last message in MQTT to prevent that the application going to be closed*", your intention is not clear and you are not showing the error received

Comment: Yes I'm sorry my english is really bad, I correct my question.
"prevent" replace by "warn"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the help of Kostek (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71485487/16188409), I found the solution, by adding the "REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" to the manifest as the post below said :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67770107/16188409

Comment: Cool, great work, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Neither the onDestroy method nor onStop is guaranteed to be called.

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it.

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

I believe this could change from device to device. Your observation that it happened while the battery saving option was ON could be very true in this case.

As for the solution maybe take a look at bound services and see if they are better fit for your scenario: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Stay strong and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I'm now sure that the battery saving changed how work my app, but unfortunately, by using the Bound Service and by using the onUnBind instead of the onDestroy methode to send a last MQTT message, this didn'twork too.
I will continue to search. And if you have another idea, I'm here !!
As soon as I found the solution, I will post it here.